# Opening window once another window is closed after a certain amount of time in python

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to have a window open once another window closes after a certain amount of time with tkinter? I know the `after` command will help close a window after a specified time and I've implemented that, but is there a way to get a subsequent window to open after that same amount of time?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In the function called `after` close the window and open the new window ... hmm ... what is exactly your question?

Comment: So I tried using the 'after' command to open the 2nd window after I closed the 1st window, and the change I made was substituting the destroy command with a mainloop command. So it looked something like this: 'new_win.after(3000, lambda:new_win.mainloop())'. That didn't work at all, though